# Many-to-Many Nested Attributes in Rails 4 (with strong parameters)

Tags: many-to-many, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been trying to figure this one out for a few days now. I am using Rails 4 (with the updated mass assignment technique) and trying to use nested attributes with a many-to-many relationship. My record is saving to the DB but everything is nil and I'm getting an "Unpermitted parameters: school, alumnis, prospects" error in my logs.

Here's what I have:

**referral.rb**

```
class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :school
 belongs_to :alumni
 belongs_to :prospect
end
```

**alumni.rb**

```
class Alumni < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals
  has_many :prospects, through: :referrals

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :referrals
end
```

**school.rb**

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals
  has_many :prospects, through: :referrals
  has_many :alumnis, through: :referrals

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :referrals
end
```

**prospect.rb**

```
class Prospect < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals
  has_many :alumnis, through: :referrals

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :referrals
end
```

**referrals_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @referral = Referral.create(referral_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @referral.save
      # ReferralMailer.referrer_email(@referral).deliver
      # ReferralMailer.referral_email(@referral).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to @referral, notice: 'Referral was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @referral }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @referral.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_referral
    @referral = Referral.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def referral_params
    params.require(:referral).permit(prospects_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :email], alumnis_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :email], schools_attributes: [:name])

  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@referral) do |f| %>
  <% if @referral.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@referral.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this referral from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @referral.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :school do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :name, "School Name" %>
    <%= builder.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :alumnis do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :first_name, "First Name" %>
    <%= builder.text_field :first_name %>

    <%= builder.label :last_name, "Last Name" %>
    <%= builder.text_field :last_name %>

    <%= builder.label :email, "Email" %>
    <%= builder.text_field :email %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :prospects do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :first_name, "First Name" %>
    <%= builder.text_field :first_name %>

    <%= builder.label :last_name, "Last Name" %>
    <%= builder.text_field :last_name %>

    <%= builder.label :email, "Email" %>
    <%= builder.text_field :email %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**server log output**

```
Processing by ReferralsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ee+rREUU/0wGzNFTEaMxr8oRStaA53X9fmDrlVRyrD8=", "referral"=>{"school"=>{"name"=>"asdf"}, "alumnis"=>{"first_name"=>"asdf", "last_name"=>"asfd", "email"=>"asdf"}, "prospects"=>{"first_name"=>"asdf", "last_name"=>"asdf", "email"=>"asdf"}}, "commit"=>"Create Referral"}
Unpermitted parameters: school, alumnis, prospects
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "referrals" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 12 Jul 2013 03:49:06 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 12 Jul 2013 03:49:06 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/referrals/68
```

**Referral Record**

```
=> #<Referral id: 68, created_at: "2013-07-12 03:49:06", updated_at: "2013-07-12 03:49:06", school_id: nil, alumni_id: nil, prospect_id: nil>
```

Comment: I wonder if it matters that the keys passed into your params are strings, but the keys in `referral_params` are symbols. However, after reading Jon Wheeler's suggestion, I think that's the fix.

Comment: @cpeterson : i am facing the same issue

Can you please explain me, how did you resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should pass also 'id' in each of your nested model params try :

```
def referral_params
    params.require(:referral).permit(prospects_attributes: [:id,:first_name, :last_name, :email], alumnis_attributes: [:id,:first_name, :last_name, :email], schools_attributes: [:id,:name])    
end
```

Have swing

Cheers

Comment: That didn't look like it worked. Does the ID need to be set somehow? I'm thinking it's set once the object is saved, but it's still nil with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You parameters are not being past to the controller as strong parameters is expecting.

From you server log:

```
"referral" => {
  "school"  => { 
     "name" => "asdf" }, 
  "alumnis" => { 
    "first_name" => "asdf", 
    "last_name"  => "asfd", 
    "email"      => "asdf" 
  }, 
  "prospects" => {
    "first_name" => "asdf", 
    "last_name"  => "asdf", 
    "email"      => "asdf" 
  }
 }
```

Strong parameters is expecting `prospects_attributes`, `alumnis_attributes` and `schools_attributes` so `prospects`, `alumnis` and `school` are getting blocked and the objects are getting created without any attributes.