# How to give multiple many-many relationship between tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**SOLVED Please read more at the end of the question and in my answer below.**

My question is that what will be relationship between `user,assessment,question,answer with user_answer`

Relationship which I had defined

- One assessment has_many questions
- One question has_many answers

My Scheme file

```
create_table "assessments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
end

create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.string   "answer_label"
    t.integer  "answer_value"
end

create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "assessment_id"
    t.text     "effective_text"
    t.text     "ineffective_text"
end

 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "encrypted_password"
 end

create_table "user_answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "assessment_id"
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.integer  "answer_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

Help me, If you can

Thanks

Comment: Your question really isn't clear to me, but just as a reminder, the join table should be `answers_users` rather than `users_answers`.  Relations are *always* in alphabetical order when you do things the Rails way.

Comment: @David Hoelzer : Let me know which part of this question you don't understand?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer : Here just i want to know relationship between user_answer with other tables?

Comment: Go through [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) chapter from Rails Guides

Comment: Ok ..So need the ruby code  on following schema ?? M I Correct

Comment: @Vinay : Nope, I want to know what is the relation between user and user_answer AND what is the relation between assessment and user_answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer to your Question One by one

> I want to know what is the relation between user and user_answer

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, through: user_answers
  has_many :assessment, through: user_answers
end

class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :assessment
end
```

> what is the relation between assessment and user_answer?

```
class Assessment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: user_answers
end
```

I would strongly suggested to you read out [Stackoverflow- Can a foreign key be NULL and/or duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7573590/3098330)

Hope this help you !!!

Comment: @Vijay : Thanks for reply.

Please explain me what relationship you have given?

Many-many relationship between User and Assessement?
Many-many relationship between User and Answer?
Middle table is UserAnswer

Am i right?

Comment: @JigarBhatt First and Foremost one I m not _Vijay_ :P ..Okey As you might asked I answered your exact Question, As you had created _join table_  as _user_answer_ . I really dont think this is a best way to save the record.Because For each records for _user_answer_ would have at-least one foreign_key would be nil.

Comment: i am sorry.


class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, through: user_answers

end
is this code fine for answer model?

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help.

You are Genious.

Comment: Welcome But i must say I'm Also in process of Learning .Glad It Helps :)

Comment: I am working on has many through relationship with nested form.same as below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607239/many-to-many-nested-attributes-in-rails-4-with-strong-parameters

can you please help me to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: @JigarBhatt What error you are getting ? Or How might i could resolve your issue ?